# Tableau action filter to show show non-relevant values only

Tags: tableau-desktop

I've been trying to create an action filter in tableau that will allow me to see only non relevant values. For example, I have sales data at a product and customer level. With action filters, when we select a product, we can see only those customers that have bought the selected product. But what I want is to show the customers that didn't purchase this product. I've tried to explain my requirement in the below image with data. Could someone help me with a workaround for this? TIA.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZY7i.png)

Comment: The options available in Action Filters wont support this case, however this is an interesting idea. please share this with the Tableau community